# Automatic Facebook ad form data warehouse insights

Tags: facebook, api, data-warehouse, star-schema

I have a client's data warehouse in which I fetch a lot of data. I have a star schema for Newsletters and global emails. I also set up client's ads on Facebook and create audiences to target them right.

So, is it possible to connect the graph API/Marketing API to my database and make ad automatization?
For example, I would like to remarket people who for haven't opened an email. For sure I could do a select on my database (something like `SELECT * email from newsletters where NLT_ID=1 and where opened="NO";` and then add these email in a new audience and target these people with the same content. But is it possible to achieve that (more) automatically?
If yes, with which program, is this Azure?
Please provide example also in your answer.

Comment: C# with LINQ syntax allows you to mingle heterogeneous data sets in single declarations.

Comment: Oh yes! Thx a lot! Now I need to practice c# ;)